# Run Image Asset Studio To start Image Asset Studio - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio-3.5

In the Project window, I select the Android view. But
Right-clicking the res folder doesn't give me the option/gesture to select **New > Image Asset** as it is not there?

[https://developer.android.com/studio/images/write/adaptive_icon_wizard.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJy6g.png)

> Android Studio 3.5.3
>   Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548, built on November 15, 2019
>   JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   macOS 10.15.3
>
> Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>   Framework • revision 27321ebbad (2 months ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
>   Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
>   Tools • Dart 2.7.0